# TFS Build Server Directory name

Tags: tfs, build-server

I am not a developer nor am I the Application Lifecycle Manager. I pull the latest builds from TFS Build Server along with the latest code and I import them in AppScan source for analysis (security tool). Against each security findings there is a class name within which the findings were found along with the directory where the class is located.

Builds are created automatically during a certain time of the day. As mentioned earlier the directory names change every time after a new build and a new number (highlighted below) is introduced. It is not sequential, does anyone know of TFS build server assigns these numbers.

C:\Builds**12**\Development
C:\Builds**14**\Development
C:\Builds**13**\Development
C:\Builds**15**\Development

Comment: If you [set your build definition to move completed builds to a drop folder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/bb778394.aspx), you will have a more predictable folder structure.

Answer (score 0):

TFS will create folders based on the following.

DriveLetter\Builds\$(BuildAgentId)\$(BuildDefinitionPath)

so if you have 1 controller with 4 agents on a clean install you would get

Drive:\Builds\1\$(BuildDefinitionPath)
Drive:\Builds\2\$(BuildDefinitionPath)
Drive:\Builds\3\$(BuildDefinitionPath)
Drive:\Builds\4\$(BuildDefinitionPath)

Your Build definition is the name of the build definition and then each subsequent build is stored underneath, with each individual build getting its own folder.

these settings are available on the [Build Agent properties screen.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399135.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

These are transient files and you cant rely on them being there. They are only used as part of the build. You would be better doing a "Get" from TFS at the appropriate Changeset number for the build and using the binaries from the drop folder.